# maven pom validation failing on dependency

Tags: validation, jenkins, maven-3, pom.xml

My application has a dependency on a pom and that pom has some validation errors, which is causing my jenkins build to fail (maven3). The validation errors are just that one of the build profiles for that dependency is not valid, but I'm just using the binary so that shouldn't affect my project.

Is there a way to ignore this error or a workaround (other than modifying the 3rd party pom)?

Edit:

The actual error message is:

[WARNING] The POM for com.jidesoft:jide-oss:jar:2.10.2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 2 problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.jidesoft:jide-oss:2.10.2

[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for aqua_ui:ui:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${basedir}/libs/ui.jar @

[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for aqua_ui:jrs:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${basedir}/libs/JavaRuntimeSupport.jar @

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: I have posted the error message.

Comment: It looks like an Maven 1 artifact ? Do you have the real name of the artifact?

Comment: yes, it's com.jidesoft:jide-oss version 2.10.2

Comment: If my answer won't help you, please paste your POM and console output. We're guesing a little bit about what's going on there and because you're not using private, internal 3rd party artifact, I assume it's not a problem for you to paste it.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it and don't have such problem. Everything is OK when building my artifact that depends on `com.jidesoft:jide-oss:2.10.2`. One thing that just came to my mind is Maven version you are using. First releases of Maven 3 are REALLY buggy and cause many strange problems. IMHO first release that really (I mean really) works is 3.0.4. If you have one of previous Maven 3 version, try upgrade and tell if it works.

Comment: Michael, I am currently using maven 3.0.4. I have edited my post with the full error log. The maven build still runs but jenkins is failing the build because of this error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why this works for you, locally.

Do you have, in your local machine, ${basedir}/libs/ui.jar present ?
If yes, is this available for the Jenkins server ? Does Jenkins gets the project sources from SVN/CVS/GIT ?

Your error occurs because your dependency has a **System** dependency, so Maven does not try to get it in the repo, but at the given location instead.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>aqua_ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>ui</artifactId>
         <version>5.0</version>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/ui.jar</systemPath>
```